# as3 how to perfom different actions if button is clicked or not

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

I am a complete n00b.

I'm working on a game. Basically, I have to perform no action if a button is pressed on a certain keyframe, but if it's not clicked, I need the scene to proceed until a certain point and then go to another frame.

In my stupid head I thought: if I can create an empty global variable I could input "something" when the button is clicked on my frame and check on a latter frame "if globalvar == "something": nothing happens, else: gotoAndPlay(where I need)"

Explanatory image:
[image]

Apparently that's not how AS3 works. So what can I do?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var pressed = "no";

function work(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    pedal.visible = false;
    cursor_mc.visible = false;
    pressed = "yes"
}

pedal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, work);
```

This is what I've got when the action needs to be performed.

Then I would put (I've never written an if statement in as3)

```
if (pressed == "no") {
    gotoAndPlay(some other frame);
}
```

This would be put on a complete different frame **AND LAYER** from the previous so that the part in between is still played.

Comment: Your logic sounds correct.  You should be able to set a variable or boolean, then check it's condition and if true it will do something, if false it will do something else.  Are you able to post sample code?  The order in which you are doing things may be the problem.

Comment: I've added some more details, sadly I'm very ew to As, don't even know if the syntax is correct, I've been checking the adobe help, seems ok to me.

Comment: Hey Neurone00, a belated welcome to the community. If you have a bit of money available, invest in one of the AS3 books mentioned on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/actionscript-3/info. I personally recommend the ActionScript 3.0 Bible. It's what we use at my company.

Comment: Strangely my solution, exactly as it is above, worked perfectly.Thank you Jason for the suggestion, I'll take it into consideration!

Answer (score 2):

You got to add a new event, and ENTER_FRAME event to which will fire a function on every frame. There you could check whether the button is pressed. For example:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateFunction);
function updateFunction(e:Event){
    if(pressed == "no"){
        if(currentFrame == frame number when you want to check){
            gotoAndPlay(some other frame);
        }
    }
}
```